# Can we add two css files for iPad web App

Tags: ios, ipad, html

I have web app i want that it should implement two css files if it is runing on browser then it should run css1 and if runing offline from Home desktop of ipad then it should use css2

Answer (score 0):

I will cut my answer to two, the 1st part will detect if running on iPad or iPhone , the second will call different CSS files

Part 1 - detect if running on iOS device

```
-(NSString *)isRunningOniOS
{
    NSString *yourDevice = nil;
    if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
       yourDevice = @"iPad";
    } else {
       yourDevice = @"iPhone";
    }
    return yourDevice;
}
```

you can test this by running the following code anywhere inside the class, for example:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    //
    NSLog(@"Your device = %@",[self isRunningOniOS]);
}
```

Part 2 - Custom CSS

Based on Part 1 , we can now do this:

```
NSLog(@"Your device = %@",[self isRunningOniOS]);
    NSString *cssPath;
    if ([self isRunningOniOS]){
        cssPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"iosCSSfile" ofType:@"css"];
    } else {
        cssPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"browserCSSfile" ofType:@"css"];    
    }
    NSLog(@"CSS file= %@",cssPath);
```

Comment: i am using HTML5 how i will write a Class in that with ViewDidLoad Method